# Resolving added and deleted conflicts Git

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

I have a branch `release-x.x.x` that I would like to merge into the master. However it has hundreds of merge conflicts when I do a pull request. I think this is due to a Swift 3 migration I performed. Either way I want to use all the versions of the files in `release-x.x.x` when merged into `master`. I have done `checkout release-x.x.x` and `git merge -s recursive -X ours master`. I am doing it in reverse so I can resolve conflicts on the `release-x.x.x` and then create a pull request on `master` and keep all the commit history.

When I run `git status`, this is some of the output:

```
added by us:     Pods/FirebaseCrash/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseCrash.framework/FirebaseCrash
added by us:     Pods/FirebaseCrash/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseCrash.framework/Headers/FIRCrashLog.h
added by us:     Pods/FirebaseCrash/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseCrash.framework/Headers/FirebaseCrash.h
added by us:     Pods/FirebaseCrash/Frameworks/frameworks/FirebaseCrash.framework/Modules/module.modulemap
deleted by them: Pods/FirebaseCrash/README.md
deleted by them: Pods/FirebaseCrash/batch-upload
deleted by them: Pods/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym
deleted by them: Pods/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym-util.bash
deleted by us:   Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/CHANGELOG.md
added by us:     Pods/Intercom/Intercom/Intercom.framework/Versions/A/Intercom
both added:      MyProject/Base.lproj/Localizable.stringsdict
both deleted:    MyProject/Localizable.stringsdict
both added:      MyProject/en-HK.lproj/Localizable.stringsdict
```

I assume I want to keep anything with `added by us`, `both added` and also keep anything marked `deleted by them`, so I have staged these files. How do I deal with `deleted by us` and `both deleted`? If I try `git rm Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/CHANGELOG.md` I get the error: `Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/CHANGELOG.md: needs merge`. Am I on the right track here at all?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you're on the right track. To resolve the merge in the way you specified, you should `git rm` any files that are marked `deleted by us` or `both deleted`.

The `needs merge` error should be just a warning. When I run `git rm <file>` on a file deleted by one side in a merge, I get:

```
<file>: needs merge
rm '<file>'
```

And a subsequent `git status` shows that the file has been deleted (and the deletion has been staged).